# Unknown Error in drawable folder

Tags: android, drawable

Am create an app that integrating zxing. I followed as per this site http://damianflannery.wordpress.com/2011/06/13/integrate-zxing-barcode-scanner-into-your-android-app-natively-using-eclipse/.  Now i have error in drawable folder. Please guide me.

Thanks in Advance.[image]

Comment: If you go to the "Problems" pane you can see what the error says and probably fix it.

Comment: check your resource names inside this folder, maybe there are not allowed signs...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are dividing according to `density` to achieve multiple size support inside your android app.

But there ain't any `xxhdpi`.

```
ldpi    Resources for low-density (ldpi) screens (~120dpi).
mdpi    Resources for medium-density (mdpi) screens (~160dpi). (This is the baseline density.)
hdpi    Resources for high-density (hdpi) screens (~240dpi).
xhdpi   Resources for extra high-density (xhdpi) screens (~320dpi).
nodpi   Resources for all densities. These are density-independent resources. 
tvdpi   Resources for screens somewhere between mdpi and hdpi; approximately 213dpi. This is not considered a "primary" density group. It is mostly intended for televisions and most apps shouldn't need it—providing mdpi and hdpi resources is sufficient for most apps and the system will scale them as appropriate.
```

**There's no need of `drawable-xxhdpi` inside `res/` of project. So please  remove it.**

For more details follow up these [configuration qualifiers](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#qualifiers)